# floating images in a layer, inside another layer

Tags: html

I have the following HTML to center images and links within a layer:

edit: a better example

```
<style> body  { 
background-color:#000; 

color: #FFF; 

}  a  { font-family: "Broadway",
Broadway,monospace;  font-size:
14px; color:

#FFF; }

#images a {

 width: 24.99%;  display: block; 
float: left;  text-align: center;  }

#container; { top: 30%; left: 15%; }
#main { position: absolute; width: 800px; height: 600px; }
#logo { float:left; background-image:url("1.jpeg"); 
width: 104; height: 100; }


 </style> <div id="main">  <div
id="logo"> </div> <div
id="container">  <div id="images">
<a href="1.html" >
    <img src="1.gif" alt="x" width="181" height="173" border="0"
/><br />
    One </a> <a href="2.html" >
    <img src="2.gif" alt="x" width="181" height="173" border="0"
/><br />
    Two </a> <a href="3.html" >
    <img src="3.gif" alt="x" width="181" height="173" border="0"
/><br />
    Three </a> <a href="4.html" >
    <img src="4.gif" alt="x" width="181" height="173" border="0"
/><br />
    Four </a> </div></div></div>
```

Comment: How are you positioning your outer div? Seems to work OK for me using your second example.

Comment: Both examples work fine depending on how you do the positioning. Could you share with us how you want to do it? Why are you using percentages for the position?

Comment: There's a typo in your CSS - a semi-colon after #container

I'll assume that's not the issue though ;) - I think you still need to specify some sort of position on the container div though..

Comment: isnt position relative by default? surely if it is relative by default, and specifying it be 30% away from the top of #main and 15% from the side of main, that is where it should go?

Comment: No, position is static by default - so you can't use left or top. Also, your logo div + the 4 images is too wide for 800px, so they're wrapping

Comment: I want the images div to be under the logo though, so they should both be less than 800px?

Comment: If you un-float the logo div, the images will appear beneath.

Comment: I change the width of images a to 760px, and made position relative for container. Now the images layer seems to be the correct amount from top and left, but the images are stacked vertically.

Comment: See here: http://img26.picoodle.com/img/img26/3/11/20/f_whym_ba073b8.jpg

Comment: Set #images a back to 24.99%, unfloat the logo div, and set position:relative on container.

Comment: why would unfloating the logo div fix it, and what is a better way to do that? also, removing float: left; from #logo did not fix it.

Comment: You have to give an answer so I can mark you up, you have been very helpful, so thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The main div has a width of 800px, so the floated logo div (104px) + the 4 images (25% each) is too large for one line, so the final image wraps to the line below. Unfloating the logo div will start the images on a new line at the far left.
2. Position is static by default - so left and top have no effect.
3. Set `position:relative;` on the container div - be careful with IE6 though, because position:relative is a bit funny if I remember correctly.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, it makes perfect sense, but I am still unsure what caused the images to stack vertically?